# Customize Entry title

Tags: html, css, title

Well I was playing with CSS but I want to do something I have in mind and I can't do it; I don't know how to. See, [this is the website I'm testing](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes/). If you see the entry titles, they have a black background. But I want this background to occupy the whole space, like this: [See the photo.](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/i-want-this.png)

What code do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:
Negative margins to enlarge the black box, padding to keep the text back in it's original place.

It's a little dirty to do it this way, but thats the shortest solution.

Simply add this to the end of your css code:

```
#contentmiddle div.title > h1{
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Or an even shorter one:

```
#contentmiddle div.title > h1{
  margin: -40px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! It worked perfectly , you have no idea how I thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. How about accepting the right answer? :>